# Read alphabetically sorted textfile more efficiently

Tags: java, android, sorting, record

I have a large **textfile** (.txt) containing 74027 records (only one column) sorted **alphabetically**. In that records, I need to find a single record.

I have this code -

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/###/myfile.txt"));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s2), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(s1).find();
    //...
}
```

But this code takes too long to find out the record as it reads the file line by line. But since I have the records sorted alphabetically, is there any way to find the records more efficiently?

Comment: What kind of records are they? Is each record the same size? If so, you should consider using a random-access file which will allow you to do a binary search.

Comment: The records consist of names of city and each record is of different size.

Comment: the easiest is to create an array of offsets to the first word starting with given letter,  so for latin alphabet you will have 26 long words, that simple array sspeeds up your search ~26 times, provided the words are distributed more or less evenly

Answer (score 2):

Compile the pattern outside the while loop:

```
Pattern pattern =  Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s2), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    pattern.matcher(s1).find();
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A file is a sequential data structure and only admits a linear search which is, of course, linear time. To improve this the most, you need to change your data structure in order to allow random access for a binary search. I can think of several ways to do this:

1. Reformat your file format so that you can read it with random access. This means that you will need to make each record the same size.
2. Read the entire file into an appropriate in-memory data structure, perhaps simply an ArrayList.
3. Write your own data structure that provides a random-access interface to your current file format.

If none of these are feasible, then you will have to settle for minor optimizations to your current linear search. These optimizations will only affect the constant factor and not change the run-time complexity, so the benefits are much more limited than the previous suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

read in the text in large blocks, say 500 lines at a time (at 100 chars/line that's about 50K)

read in the first two full blocks.  find the first full line in the second block (find first line feed, then get up to the next line feed.)

If the first full line is alphabetically less than the pattern you are searching for, you can discard the entire previous block without doing any pattern searches on it.

repeat for each block (check the first full line and discard the prior block if it is less than the target pattern)

when you find a block where the first full line is greater than your pattern, then append the partial line at the beginning of that block (text before the first full line) to the end of the previous block and then search through the previous block for the pattern of interest.

if you reach the last block and the first full line is less than the pattern, then search through the final block for your pattern of interest.

Comment: That gives me a idea. Thanks!